# Select Multiple Item from RecyclerView and Pass selected item to another RecyclerView

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am planning to build an shop application using firebase and firebase RealtimeDatabase.

There will be be a RecyclerView of all available products.

**---I want to select multiple items from the RecyclerView and add those Items in my PurchaseRecyclerView.---**

any fruitful solution or suggestion for this issue?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: i have made the main RecyclerView where all items are showing and getting the position of ItemClickListener.

but facing problem how i would select multiple item at once and how i would pass multiple item position to another activity or RecyclerView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you could use the [`recyclerview-selection`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/recyclerview/selection/package-summary) library, coming from Google.

Once you set it up, you only need to retrieve the selected items and add them to the dataset that uses your other recyclerview's adapter.

Here there are some interesting links that might guide you in implementing the `recyclerview-selection` functionality:

- https://proandroiddev.com/a-guide-to-recyclerview-selection-3ed9f2381504
- https://github.com/marcosholgado/multiselection
- https://medium.com/coding-blocks/implementing-selection-in-recyclerview-36a9739844e0
- https://droidbyme.medium.com/android-recyclerview-with-single-and-multiple-selection-5d50c0c4c739

Also don't miss the official documentation:

- https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/recyclerview/selection/package-summary

Comment: https://droidbyme.medium.com/android-recyclerview-with-single-and-multiple-selection-5d50c0c4c739 

this one helped me thanks brother!

Answer (score 0):

handle the onItemClick with an interface and store the selected items in an ArrayList in the MainActivity and add this ArrayList to the PurchaseList's RecyclerView. Update the RecyclerView's Adapter with NotifyDataSetChanged() as user add more item.